# How to get size of a datatype/object (java.util.Date) in java?

Tags: java, sizeof, sqldatatypes

I am trying to figure out what the size of Date datatype in java is, but I couldn't find any function similar to sizeof in c/c++.

Comment: why would you want this?

Comment: `sizeof` isn't _nearly_ as well-defined in Java as in other languages.